# Should I tell people to code better while addressing their problem?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I've worked as a developer for a bit over 15 years now. As a senior backend developer, I've worked a lot with PHP in my days and PHP must be one of the most misused scripting languages in existence.

I see a lot of bad behaviour when people ask their question and misuse the language, perhaps nothing to do with the problem they have but more on a structural level.

Should I explain to them that they will have problems when they do thing on a larger scale? Their code will never run well in big production environments, or scale up. That they perhaps should consider to work more on, for an example, an OOP structure etc.

Comment: The usual fate of a prophet is getting nailed on a cross.  You can't post it as an answer.  Annotating an answer to the question with recommendations is fine, don't make it the dominant part of the answer.  A comment is okay.  Ish.

Comment: @HansPassant Surely very few prophets were nailed to crosses? :)

Comment: It took you 15 years to get where you are today. "Coding better" is unfortunately not a binary thing, it's very much an analogous process constantly learning. It the OP is learning, coding better would be the ultimate goal in any case and a natural consequence from experience and knowledge obtained along the way. But no one can learn everything at once. Even the longest path starts with a first step. My 2 cents.

Comment: Frankly, all the people who are suggesting that you might *not* tell people this is concerning to me. If I am asking a question, and you see something that I'm doing that is wrong, I *definitely* want to know about it. If I didn't want to improve, I wouldn't be asking questions. And I'd need to find a new job/hobby.

Comment: @podiluska - Yeah, far more were stoned or drawn and quartered or burned at the stake.

Comment: I think you are perfectly correct in telling people (as politely as you can manage) that their code is crap.  Very few will listen, but maybe if they hear it again and again they will take notice.

Comment: I usually try to post my context when I ask questions, so someone, who can tell that something is wrong with what I'm trying to achieve, can point it out. More often than not I can't really apply the "correct" solution for that particular problem. I mean, I'm usually aware of the fact that the code is bad, but I can't really afford to fix it all, so I end up workarounds. However it helps me avoid the "bad code" the next time I have to solve it. So, as far as I'm concerned I don't mind if someone points out what I'm doing wrong (even if it's not exactly part of question).

Comment: It isn't about clean up code. It's about teaching people about structual errors in their way to use the language.

Comment: If you have something along [these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877542/my-first-f-program) in mind, then more power to you.  Answering a specific technical question helps only people having that same problem.  Explaining a better approach to solving/avoiding a problem could help a lot more people.

Comment: And I wish to state here for the record that it's not only PHP that suffers from abuse in the hands of non-experts. This question should be more general.

Comment: Yes i can agree with that. PHP was an example of my case. But the question is in general of cause.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of the question where someone wanted to know if and how it is OK to comment on the quality of a question? This question - if I understand correctly - is about scoping the answer, the other question was about mainly about politeness and how to best demand better questions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, advice is always welcome, and I expect people to tell me if I'm doing something wrong on the conceptual level, as well as the implementational level.

The problem is not on their end, it's that most users don't (or originally have, and quickly lose) the patience to educate every user by addressing their problems while solving the problems, especially when more than half those users reply with a comment like "i dont know lol im a bginnr"

If you have the time and the patience, please do. Just don't burn out and lose your sanity along the way.

Comment: Or else we will find you in a corner, screaming "Tony the Pony".

Comment: I judge my commitment to the answer based on the person asking. Did they put any effort in their question? This lets me know if they are here to _learn_ or just looking for free code handouts.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. I will put infinitely more effort on a well written question than I would on a plz halp question.

Answer (score 32):

### Yes

There's nothing wrong with giving well-intended advice.

### But focus on the question

> Their code will never run well in big production environments, or scale up

Be wary of converting "the question" into something that it isn't. Let's be honest, most code with e.g. severe scaling problems won't see the traffic to *be* a problem. If the question isn't about something ingrained to the cause of the scaling problem - sure mention it, but don't make it the focus or only point in an answer.

If it's a comment, it can be as focussed as you wish of course.

Comment: You'd be surprised at how much poor code there is running in high traffic situations.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid well [19% of the web runs wordpress](http://venturebeat.com/2013/07/27/19-percent-of-the-web-runs-on-wordpress/) so - sure there is a lot of high-traffic sites running poor code =). However, the proportion of code shown on SO with "problems" that will be used to the point where scaling problems manifest themselves is likely to be a tiny fraction.

Comment: I think someone writing things like `"SELECT * FROM tab WHERE val = $val"` deserve a comment about SQL injections. You don't have to post an answer for this, and that's what comments are for.

Answer (score 3):

You ought, I'd say.

Definitely, something like *The PHP tag Code* should be developed, with prototype answers for most questions, like one were used while "switch from mysql to mysqli" pointless hysteria. Say, an answer that hits the OP with ruler every time they are trying to write some business logic using raw DB api, and offers an ORM-based example instead. And so on.

The mission, though, impossible.

Given as much rep-whores as we have, and as deep ignorance level as average PHP user at, you will always lose to hasty shitcode answer from the former, and to eternal fear that PHP users feel against any approach that is slightly more complex than snippets they learned from w3fools a century ago.

Answer (score -1):

There are many different ways in coding to find a solution of a particular problem.

The best way to explain / convince the other people is  , show them live demo.

I am just considering performance as an example.

Show them the performance related issues in the implemented code and after that modify code in better way and show them improved performance.

So this will be the best way to show them the difference.

I am just sharing my thoughts on the questions above.

Comment: Your answer is to rewrite _all_ the code? Create a live demo? Setup a performance benchmark? There's no mention of actually _answering_ the question and ... [I don't think that's viable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tk6Mjg3_eq0).

Comment: No i don't mean to rewrite all the code.

This depends on scenario ,
For E.G
1> If you to change the 'mysql' to 'mysqli' --> Make a branch of code using some repository OR create a backup of old code  and try to convert it and see what is out come.

2>Second example ,  In case ,some big code is written in  a particular file , you can identify , how to remove extra lines of code , what are alternate methods by which we can reduce the code lines and enhance the performance.
E.G : use jQuery filters , instead of $.each.

Answer (score -14):

No. Your advise is outside of the problem domain. Like in OOP, I vote to separate concerns.

Comment: What if it isn't?

Comment: Sometimes bad practices can lead to problems... Then you'll get more questions from the same user.

Comment: @Cody: Then it is outside the scope of the original question. The poster asked about advise that has "perhaps nothing to do with" with the problem. If your advise may be related with the problem ("perhaps" ) but you are not sure, then I think it is of course OK to give it. If on the other hand you rather think your advise would be unrelated and it is just stuff that you somehow dislike (coding style, language) then I would not give it.

Comment: So e.g. pointing out that the sql used isn't escaping inputs and can easily be exploited is out of scope?